# What Happened to `Recent Files' Feature in Document Viewer (Evince)?

Tags: evince

Most of the currently available applications provide a way to open the recently accessed files from it.

In the previous versions of Document Viewer, I could see a list of recently opened files. However, in recent versions of Document Viewer, I find that this previously available feature is no longer present.

When you use the `File` menu after launching Document Viewer, there is no list of recent files.

[image]

When you click on `Open`, the `Recently Used` entry, available by default in other Ubuntu applications is not there.

[image]

Only after you have opened a file, and click on `File`->`Open`, you can get a list of recent files.

[image]

I feel that a very useful feature has been withdrawn. Or am I missing something here?

I am using Document Viewer 3.10.3 in Ubuntu 14.04, updated regularly.

Do you think there is way out of the situation?

Comment: I think you don't have a problem with that. I tried it and it's the same with me.

Answer (score 3):

Seems to have been broken in 3.10.3-0ubuntu4 (debian/patches/0001-Port-to-GMenuModel-and-add-menu-bar.patch

So last working in 14.04 was 3.10.3-0ubuntu3 (- in File menu) or previous to that in the gnome's toolbar gear menu dropdown > recent

Filed bug - https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/evince/+bug/1365296